# Identifying and storing cell location(address) in HTML tables

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any attribute which can Identify a particular cell location in HTML table?
Also, Can I store that attribute(cell address) in a variable and later use it to update the value of that cell?

For e.g.

Lets say I have a 4 X 4 Table. and I want to update Row 1 Column 3, Row 2 Column 4 and Row 3 Column 2, How do I save a the locations(addresses) of these cells which I can later use to update the cells?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very possible.

I mocked up a little something: http://jsfiddle.net/NBmb4/1/

You could save each cell you needed into variables and use those to later reference/modify that cell.

```
var theCellImLookingFor = cellAtCoord(3, 2);
// modify the cell as needed.
```

Comment: How can I capture the value of cell using cell coordinates?

Comment: Using jQuery: `cellAtCoord(3, 3).text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is a way to do that but not "automatically".
You always can write a javascript function, probably with two nested cicles, and, after getting a reference a cell (''), assign an 'id' value to each one.